# Is there a way to expire unobfuscated javascript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

Currently, our developers unobfuscate the javascript code so they can better QA our code in staging before we release to production.

However, sometimes, they forget to obfuscate the code before releasing to production.

I was wondering if there is a way to expire unobfuscated javascript so that, even if the QA developers forget to obfuscate the js it will auto obfuscate the js after a certain time frame (say 12 hours)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not obfuscate itself so this question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Obfuscation is done by a separate tool in the build/release process.  What you need is to improve/automate part of the release process to remove the chances of human error in that process.  This can either be done with a more rigorous manual process or with more automatation.

In general, the QA team should be testing the EXACT same code that gets deployed on the final site so if that's obfuscated, that's what QA should test.  So, first of all, I'd review what QA is doing and why.  They should be testing the obfuscated code.

If QA needs to review the unobfuscated code for any reasons (I can't think of any likely reasons myself), then they should make their own copy of the code on their own systems that is unobfuscated and should not be putting the unobfuscated code anywhere in the release process.

Lastly, it sounds like you would benefit from building an automated release process that does the obfuscation and deploys to both the QA test environment and the same process deploys to your production servers.  That guarantees that obfuscation is in place and that QA is testing the exact same bits that would go to production when it's released.

Comment: "you would benefit from building an automated release process that does the obfuscation and deploys to both the QA test environment and the same process deploys to your production servers" - Any ideas/suggestions on how to do that? or where to look how to do that?

Comment: It depends a bit on what toolset you're using in your build environment and what platform you're using.  It can be a simple as batch files/shell scripts that run other programs and copy files around or it can be a tool like a make system that lets you set up dependency rules and then carrys out executes various programs/scripts per your rules.  I have a windows-based project that just uses a command line batch file to run a program that minimizes and combines multiple JS files and copies the results to the build output location.

Answer (score 4):

No, what you are asking for does not make sense.

The problem is with your process: why is the obfuscation happening before your QA developers get the product? Why is it not between them and the final customer release (even if it is necessary)?

Try redesigning the path the code takes between your core developers and the customers' hands instead of looking for a technical solution for a business problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your process is wrong.  If the devs need unobfuscated javascript for debugging, make it such that the server itself has a debug flag to return unobfuscated code.  Default to obfuscated code.  Require both be present.  Work the obfuscation into a release script in the release process.

You don't want QA testing something other than the build you're deploying, so obfuscating after the fact is unideal (imagine you hit a bug in the obfuscator... as likely as it seems, would you rather catch it in QA, or not until it hits prod?

By defaulting to obfuscated code, but allowing plain code via say session state or cookie, you get both correctly tested releases, and easily debuggable ones.